# How to handle broken link for static content from assets folder in angular 7

Tags: angular

I have a routing like

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/firstpage', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: "firstpage", component : FirstpageComponent },
{ path: "pagenotfound", loadChildren: './error/error.module#ErrorModule'},
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/pagenotfound'}
```

I have link in a content like below, which will be broken

```
<a href="../../../assets/pdf/sample.pdf" target="_blank">Sample PDF</a>
```

When I try to access above pdf link I am getting redirect to "firstpage" instead of "pagenotfound"

If anyone has any idea on how to resolve this, please help.

Comment: Paths should be relative to your index file. And a broken link doesn't decide your Angular route. What's your problem exactly ?

Comment: Path is good for the PDF (http://localhost:4200/assets/pdf/sample.pdf), but this PDF file is not present on localhost (intentionally) and when I click on the link it redirects me to "firstpage"

Comment: I am certain `../../../assets/pdf/sample.pdf` should be `assets/pdf/sample.pdf`. But even without that, if you use it as a link and not a download link, it is normal for your error to appear. Just add a download attribute to your link.

Comment: `../../../assets/pdf/sample.pdf` and `assets/pdf/sample.pdf` both works for me, but redirect is not happening to correct page i.e. "pagenotfound"

Comment: I have just explained to you why it is not working and gave you the solution. Did you try it ?

Comment: Adding download attribute doesn't help, instead it is trying to download the file, where as I am trying to open it in new window and do redirect when file not present

Comment: You can not test if a file is present or not with Angular. For the new page, you have to provide an absolute URL and a `target="_blank"` attribute.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using `router-link` directive if you want Angular to handle the route.

`<a [routerLink]="['../../../assets/pdf/sample.pdf']">Sample PDF</a>`

**Edit**
Note if your path is static (I assumed that it was just an example) you have to remove the brackets.
`<a routerLink="['../../../assets/pdf/sample.pdf']">Sample PDF</a>`
Otherwise the router seems to try to route to `/assets/pdf/sample.pdf`, which might cause to not trigger your fallback route.

**Edit II**
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-ayqqon) example that includes opening in new tab.

Comment: I think more it should be relative to index.html without using routerlink: `<a href="./assets/pdf/sample.pdf">Sample PDF</a>`

Comment: It's recommended to use routerLink in angular application. In this he should use routerlink with path './assets/pdf/sample.pdf'. If you are fetching with httpClient you can use httpClient.get(assets/pdf/sample.pdf)

Comment: What it "should be" is depending on the usecase IMHO. Hamed asked to route to a fallback route and this is not possible if the link isn't used with the Angular routerLink directive.

Comment: What is the result?

Comment: Seems to me it still doesn't get handeled by Angular, but instead only goes up to the root folder where it stops and therefore the path is `''` and this again gets routed by Angular.
Check if your imports are correct and routerLink works as expected or search if the [HasLocationStrategy](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/routing-strategies/) might cause problems (I don't belive so, but how knows).

Comment: Here is a [Stackbitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-ayqqon) that might help you. I forked from another router example and didn't rename all the components so don't be confused of this.

Comment: `useHash: false` solved this problem, but now named anchor links are not working

Comment: But the routing problem/your question is solved? (I wouldn't mind if you accept the answer if it was helpful)  
Please open a new question for the anchor problem with an example, as this discussion is getting to broad for the comment area.